# Why does both the multiple method program have different results

Tags: java

I just wrote a program to increase the value of arrays by 1. But, when i used an enhanced for loop I could not add get the same result.......
USING FOR LOOP

```
class array{
public static void main(String args[]){
    int rajath[]={11,22,33,44};
    change(rajath);
    for(int x:rajath){
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}

public static void change (int x[]){
    for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++){
        x[i]++;
    }
}
}
```

ENHANCED FOR LOOP

```
    class array{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int rajath[]={11,22,33,44};
        change(rajath);
        for(int x:rajath){
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }
    
    public static void change (int x[]){
        for(int i:x ){
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That i is the element of the array, not the element IN the array.

Comment: An enhanced for loop will copy the value of the array, so it won't change the value in the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your enhanced for loop is equivalent to :

```
for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++){
    int k = x[i];
    k++;
}
```

which is not the same as your regular for loop.

Your regular for loop increments the elements of the array, while your enhanced for loop increments copies of those elements.

Answer (score 1):

In Enhanced for loop you're incrementing the block variable `i`
In For loop you're incrementing the element in the array